# Non character argument in R string split function (strsplit)

Tags: string, r, for-loop, strsplit

This works

```
x <- "0.466:1.187:2.216:1.196"
y <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ":")))
```

Values of `blat$LRwAvg` all look like `X` above but this doesn't work

```
for (i in 1:50){
  y <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(blat$LRwAvg[i], "\\:")))
  blat$meanLRwAvg[i]=mean(y)
}
```

Because of:

> Error in strsplit(blat$LRwAvg[i], "\:") : non-character argument

It doesn't matter if I have one, two or null backslashes.

What's my problem? (Not generally, I mean in this special task, technically)

Comment: What is the output of `class(blat$LRwAvg)`, and can you give us some data from `blat$LRwAvg`

Comment: @AWE It is an error type. coerce the argument to character , `as.character(blat$LRwAvg)`

Comment: @alexwhan I noticed that so deleted my comment, but not quickly enough :$. It looks like its a problem with factors. So coerce to character as @agstudy suggests, or use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the data.frame.

Comment: @alexwhan, class(blat$LRwAvg) = factor, @agstudy, `blat$LRwAvg <- as.character(blat$LRwAvg)` before loop fixed it!

Comment: @AWE you can answer and accept your own question.

Comment: Isn't it more appropriate that agstudy answers it so I can accept?

Comment: @AWE it doesn't matter. It is even encouraged to answer his own question. So answer and accept it please.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As agstudy implied `blat$LRwAvg <- as.character(blat$LRwAvg)` before loop fixed it

```
blat$meanLRwAvg <- blat$gtFrqAvg #or some other variable in data frame with equal length
blat$LRwAvg <- as.character(blat$LRwAvg)
for (i in 1:50){
  y <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(blat$LRwAvg[i], "\\:")))
  blat$meanLRwAvg[i]=mean(y)
}
```